# Subplot of two graphs in Python not showing correctly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to print 2 graphs based on some training data in Python but it looks like subplot it's not working, it's making me two separate figures, this is not a problem, the problem it's that the second graph it's empty... Here it's my first plot:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("Boston.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Actual value of medv": y_test, "Predicted": y_pred}
)  
df1 = df.head()
plt.subplot(211)  # here idk why it's not working
# plot the Bar graph showing the comparison of 
#  Actual and Predicted values.
df1.plot(
    kind="bar", figsize=(16, 10)
)  
plt.show()  
# Though my model is not very precise, some predicted 
#  percentages are close to the actual ones.
plt.subplot(212)
# Plot the linear regression line
fig = plt.scatter(X_train, y_train)

# Create a range of points. Compute 
#  yhat=coeff1*x + intercept 
#  and plot the regression line.
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 20)
figura1 = plt.plot(x, linreg.coef_ * x + linreg.intercept_, color="red")
plt.legend(["Regression line", "data"])
```

Here you can see how my graph it's looking right now: [image: with subplot on]

and here it's with deleting subplots: [image: without subplot]

CSV file can be found here: https://github.com/tvganesh/MachineLearning-RandPython/blob/master/Boston.csv

Comment: Call `plt.show()` only after the second `plt.plot()`

Comment: @Jona if I'm doing this the output would still be the same...

Comment: First, you can plot data that anyone can reproduce (and easily, i.e. without an external file) and second, you should get rid of all extra line (like grid, labels, etc).

Comment: @Jona I don't think the file can be uploaded here...

Comment: Not a `neural-network` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut it is because it's a csv file that it's trained in order to do some tasks, I didn't post all the code.

Comment: This is clearly a plotting issue, and the source of the data to be plotted is irrelevant. Tags are about the *content* of the question, not its context; had your data been generated by a sensor on a spaceship would not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering` (even if the tag really existed). Please keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib `subplots` will returns an array of Axes objects (if you ask for several subplots). Use those Axes objects to identify where the data should be plotted.

Here is an example based on your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

y_test=[3,4,5]
y_pred=[6,7,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Actual value of medv": y_test, "Predicted": y_pred}
)  
df1 = df.head()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
# plot the Bar graph showing the comparison of 
#  Actual and Predicted values.
df1.plot(
    kind="bar", figsize=(16, 10), ax=ax1
)  
# Though my model is not very precise, some predicted 
#  percentages are close to the actual ones.
# Plot the linear regression line
ax2.scatter([1,2,1], [1,2,3])

# Create a range of points. Compute 
#  yhat=coeff1*x + intercept 
#  and plot the regression line.
ax2.plot([1,2,1], color="red")
plt.legend(["Regression line", "data"])
plt.show()
```

[image: Subplots mixing panda and matplotlib]

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the pandas plotting methods which `ax` you want the plot to go on:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "reg_x": np.random.randint(0, 40, 100),
        "reg_y": np.random.randint(0, 40, 100),
        "y": np.random.randint(0, 50, 100),
        "x": np.random.randint(1, 3, 100),
    }
)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,7))
df.plot.scatter("reg_x", "reg_y", ax=ax1)
# Mock a regression line
ax1.plot([0,40],[18,22],'g-')
df.plot.bar("x", ax=ax2)
```

[image: Example of two subplots]